# how to check for authentication of users login in custom application using CMIS in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I have made custom webapp using CMIS with which I am able to get the document from repository of alfresco and also able to upload document from my webapp into the repository of alfresco. But it is not checking for user authentication, if I try to login with random user who doesn't have access to the alfresco repository he/she is also able to login.

I am using below code:

```
    public Session getSession() {

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {



        prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

        ALFRSCO_ATOMPUB_URL = "http://" + prop.getProperty("url") + ":"
                + prop.getProperty("port") + "/alfresco/service/cmis";

        System.out.println(ALFRSCO_ATOMPUB_URL);
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, prop.getProperty("USER"));

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD,
                prop.getProperty("PASSWORD"));

        // Specify the connection settings

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, ALFRSCO_ATOMPUB_URL);

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE,
                BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID,
                prop.getProperty("REPOSITORY_ID"));

        SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();

        session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession();

        return session;
    } catch (CmisUnauthorizedException ex) {

        System.out.println("you are unauthorized ");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return session;
}
    public boolean validateUser() {
    Session session = getSession();
    System.out.println("session " + session);
    if (session != null) {
        FolderBean.cmisSession = session;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!!!

Comment: can you please share code for authentication?

Comment: I have written the above code only for authentication. i.e validateUser() method

Comment: Where is getSession() function?With only this code I dont think you can authenticate.There should be username password somewhere.Dont you think so?

Comment: i am getting the session using the username and password but i also want to authenticate for the users who are a member of that repository. I have editted my above code

Comment: I didn't get you by I also want to authenticate for the users who are a member of that repository line.

Comment: I still didn't understand your question.

Comment: my question is - i have a site in alfresco and there are members of that site. now in my webapp on login screen i want to authenticate those members so that security is maintained. No external user can log into it, as  what is happening now is anyone can log into it .

Answer (score 0):

You are reading username and password from `config.properties` file.You should change that with the username and password which are entered in your webapp.

Below line in your code reads property file.

```
prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

Below is reading username  and password from property file.

```
parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, prop.getProperty("USER"));
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD,prop.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
```

Instead of that put here username and password of webapp which you are entering.